# How to run tests with Testcontainers inside docker for spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

Docker 24.0.2 + Spring boot 3.0.6 + Gradle 8.1.1 + Testcontainers:postgresql:1.18.1.
OS: MacBook Ventura Version 13.3.1

Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine

VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

COPY gradle gradle
COPY gradle.properties build.gradle settings.gradle gradlew ./
COPY ./src ./src

RUN chmod +x ./gradlew
RUN ./gradlew clean build --stacktrace
```

The goal is to have a tested jar file inside container.

Current errors:

```
Task :test

someTest > givenA_WhenB_ThenC() FAILED
  java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770
      Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException at HikariPool.java:596
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:256
```

Spent a lot of time and tried different approaches, such as run with `--privileged`, dind, etc, but without success.

So for now only one question: **How to run tests with Testcontainers inside docker for spring boot application**.

Try:

1. Docker-in-docker.
2. Socket mapping.

Max progress with `build -x test`

Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine AS build

VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

RUN apk add --no-cache docker

COPY gradle gradle
COPY gradle.properties build.gradle settings.gradle gradlew ./
COPY ./src ./src

RUN chmod +x ./gradlew
RUN ./gradlew clean build -x test --stacktrace
```

and `docker run --privileged -dti --name service-local service-local`

result inside container:

```
# docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.11
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.15
 Git commit:        dea9396e184290f638ea873c76db7c80efd5a1d2
 Built:             Thu Apr 14 23:00:14 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

```
# docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

Comment: Check the documentation https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/#docker-only-example